# DataTables not displaying rows in Google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, datatables

I am using Server Side processing of [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/index). Everything seems to be working fine  using Firefox. However, when I view the table using Chrome none of the rows are displayed and the DataTable's "Processing..." status label does not clear. The header, footer and column names of the table are shown, but no rows.

In Chrome, if I right click on the table, select inspect element, and select Console I don't see any Errors, Warnings or Logs.

All the HTML for the table looks correct, the problem seems to be I thin that DataTables hasn't put anything between the  tags.

Is there some log I could look at or tool I could use to get more diagnostic info?

What would prevent DataTables adding what it got from the JSON record to the tbody section?

I've only started using Javascript, Jquery and DataTables a couple of days ago and am unsure how to go about tracking down the problem and resolving it. Some pointers would be appreciated.

Here's my DataTable declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#cars-table').dataTable({
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bStateSave": true,
                "bServerSide": true, 
                "sAjaxSource": "/cars/get_cars_list/",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                    aoData.push({ "name": "where_select_box", "value": $("#select_box option:selected").val() } );
                    $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                    fnCallback(json)
                });
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                        { "aTargets": [0], "bVisible": false, "bSearchable": false},
                        { 
                          "aTargets": [1], 
                           "fnRender": function ( oObj ) {
                                return '<a href=\"/cars/' + oObj.aData[0] + '/\">' + oObj.aData[1] + '</a>';
                            },
                          "bSearchable": true, 
                        },
                        { "aTargets": [2], "bSearchable": true},
                        { "aTargets": [3], "bSearchable": false, "sType": 'date'},
                        { "aTargets": [4], "bSearchable": false},
                        { "aTargets": [5], "bSearchable": false},
                ]
        });
        /* Select box */
        $('#select_box').change(function() {
            // Reload data based on choice
            oTable.fnDraw();
        });
} );
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

If I start Firebug, the console shows the data being returned as a JSON data structure, but this data never gets displayed in Chrome but does in Firefox.

Here's the JSON retuned (data changed a bit as client confidential)

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 1049,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 1049,
    "aaData":[

    [
        "1",
        "car1",
        "Ford",
        "2",
        "2011-12-18",
        "159",
    ]

    ,


    [
        "2",
        "car2",
        "BMW",
        "2",
        "2011-12-18",
        "159",
    ]

    ,

    .
    .
    .

    ]
}
```

Here's the HTML for the table when I do "View Source" - as you can see tbody is empty.

```
<div style="width:75%;"> 
<div class="demo_jui"> 
<table id="cars-table" style="width:100%;" class="display" id="example"> 
        <thead> 
                <tr class="gradeA"> 
                        <th> 
                                ID 
                        </th> 
                        <th> 
                                Name
                        </th> 
                        <th> 
                                Manufacturer 
                        </th> 
                        <th> 
                                Size 
                        </th> 
                        <th> 
                                Date 
                        </th> 
                        <th> 
                                Days
                        </th> 
                </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 

        </tbody> 
</table> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the returned json and the markup generated in google chrome (or a link to the page so that we can view it?)

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti I updated the questions. Thanks.

Comment: maybe chrome is picky about those extra commas ' , ' you have in your code, check that the extension for firefox "html validator" has no errors and also that firebug is all ok, if both show no errors, maybe it will help with chrome

Comment: @max4ever tried removing the commas, but unfortunately didn't make any difference. I'll try with html validator. Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing it online it's hard to debug. I notice there's lack of one closing div element in your HMTL code. Are you able to post it online?

Comment: Since you use FireFox, try to observe the console with FireBug. Also check what the Chrome console is reporting.

Comment: Since you use FireFox, try to observe the console with FireBug. Also check what the Chrome console is reporting.

Comment: @Rumplin: When I right click on the table, select inspect element, and select Console I don't see any Errors, Warnings or Logs.

Comment: @max4ever - I think you fixed it!!! When you mentioned too many commas I thought you meant in my DT declaration. However, I just took out the final one from my JSON template and this fixed it! Thank you! Please add an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and remove the extra commas ' , '
IE7 is strict enough and used to give me javascript errors on them, maybe chrome does it too (firefox is more relaxed :D )

Comment: what commas are  you referring to ? I have a similar problem .

Comment: something like "aoColumns": [ { "sName": "ragsoc_denom"}, ] that extra column is unneded, will work on modern browsers, will give error on old IE